# Removing padding on columns makes horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanted to remove the padding from the bootstrap grid column classes.

So I did

```
.col-x {
    padding: 0;
}
```

But this is kind of breaking the whole layout because a horizontal scrollbar appears.

I've created a **[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWLbxY)** for this so you can see it.

What is causing the horizontal scrollbar and how to fix it?

Comment: If you remove the padding from col.remove the -ve margin of the row.set row margin to zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.row` has minus margins on them. Also the `.content-fluid` has padding applied to them. So you just need to add this to your CSS:

```
.row {
  margin:0;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `.row` elements nested in your columns. `.row` has a negative margin and always needs to be wrapped in a `.container`, which has padding that the negative margin offsets. The padding on your columns were doing that. I would just wrap all of your rows in `.container-fluid`

> Rows are placed within a fixed or full-width Container (.container or .container-fluid, respectively) for proper alignment.

```css
/* removing padding on columns makes horizontal scrollbar */
.column {
    padding: 0;
}


.column {
    min-height: 100vh;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.column-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.column.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-2 column sidebar">
      fixed side
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 offset-2 column content">
      <div class="column-header mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5">
              Title
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5 text-right">
              Right
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 column content">
      <div class="column-header mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5">
              Title
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 pt-4 pb-4 pl-5 pr-5 text-right">
              Right
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK but I'm using v4.

Comment: @user8121434 it's the same answer.

Comment: @user8121434 I updated my answer with the stack overflow doc on bootstrap grid (all versions). Did that not work for you? You shouldn't remove `padding` from all `.container-fluid` unless it's absolutely necessary, and in this case, it isn't - you're just mis-using the container/grid structure. You can and should fix it by using the correct markup.